# Regex expression for masking email id with unidentifiable

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Need a regex expression to create unidentifiable email address with masking, conditions like

1. If user name (before @) is less than 8 character then make the length to 8 with star (*)
2. Show only first 3 characters, rest mask using start (*)
3. If user name less than 3 character, show 1st character and make length to 8 with star(*)

e.g.

```
test123456789@gmail.com -> tes**********@gmail.com 
test1@gmail.com -> tes*****@gmail.com // make length to 8
tes@gmail.com -> t*******@gmail.com // make length to 8
```

can someone suggest the regular expression for the above

Comment: It's probably easier to get the username and then count the characters and do the replace in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think regex is a bit overkill for this type of problem, here is a solution I quickly came up with that just splits the string and checks the username length.

```
func mask(email: String) -> String? {
    let components = email.components(separatedBy: "@")
    
    guard components.count == 2 else { return nil }
    
    let username = components[0]
    
    guard !username.isEmpty else { return nil }
    
    let maskedUsername: String

    if username.count <= 3 {
        maskedUsername = "\(username[username.startIndex])\(String(repeating: "*", count: 7))"
    } else if username.count <= 8 {
        maskedUsername = "\(username.prefix(3))\(String(repeating: "*", count: 5))"
    } else {
        maskedUsername = "\(username.prefix(3))\(String(repeating: "*", count: username.count - 3))"
    }

    return "\(maskedUsername)@\(components[1])"
}
```